# Reference Spek Test in Kotlin documentation

Tags: kotlin, spek, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

I'm working with the kotlin Spek testing framework and want to link to a Spec in my documentation. But when referencing the Spec IntelliJ shows me that it doesn't find the Spec. That's understandable because the Spec is in a test root. But is there a way to link to the Spec for example by adding a link to the file or something other?